# SQLite or Core Data for large database with only queries

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite, core-data

Basically, I'm writing an iOS app that makes use of a huge database that will not be edited at all. Between these two, I'm looking for faster query speeds. I have never used any SQLite or Core Data in my developing lifetime, so before I take a dive writing anything, I want to find out which of these (or if any alternatives) would be better for my task.

Any performance data or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Neither SQLite nor Core Data was able to deliver the performance I needed (although SQLite performed better). I decided to go with SQLite (with FMDB) and use multi-threading to get rid of stutters that occur when querying multiple times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on how you want to manage your data, if you want a relational database, use sqlite and if you want to save model objects (in the sense of the model-view-controller design pattern) to a file and get them back again, use Core Data.

According to me both are same for large database, in sqlite you can use transactions for getting huge data faster.

[This](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html) link might helps you better.

Hope this helps you..

Comment: The table in link you provided answered my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For me I will always use core data whenever possible.
As it is easy to use and manage.
For more you can check these links

1. [Core Data vs SQLite 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524301/468724)
2. [Use CoreData or SQLite on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319241/468724)

Here are good tutorials of Ray Wenderlich on Core Data

1. [Core Data on iOS 5 Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)
2. [Core Data Tutorial: How To Preload/Import Existing Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data)

Comment: The thing is that I only need to read data, and most of the answers doesn't specifically answer that.

Comment: It doesn't going effect whether you are reading or writing data. These answer hold for using (by using it means reading or writing or both) core data or sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is performance, Core Data is good and can optimize the memory efficiently.
Though please have a look at this pages that can help you [Efficient storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027040/efficient-storage-of-large-amounts-of-data-in-ios) and [Concerning CoreData vs SqlLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887821/sqlite-vs-core-data-where-do-i-begin). Hope this can help.